# How do I tell the professor that I am burnt out and I want to move on

Tags: research-process, supervision

I am a first year CSE grad student. I have been working with a professor for more than half a year now. The topic looks like a deadend and I do not know how to tell him the same. Ironically, he is a nice guy and has supported me all the way through.

My prof meets with me twice a week and brainstorms with me about possible avenues of this research. The sad part, I think, my prof is not sure if a particular line of research of work may be successful or not. I am not looking for a foolproof way of doing research. At least, 5 out of 10 attempts should be successful, I guess. Correct me, if I am wrong. Currently, I just feel like a mule trying to implement his ideas. There seems to be no theoretical justification for why a particular avenue could lead to good results.  I could as well implement my own ideas and probably could have a better success rate.

This is not how I expected my project to turn out. Around 90% of the time, I just keep working on Code (writing code and fixing bugs), without any learning I can take away for future. Only 10% of the time, I just read some conference papers related to this topic. It is just too much of study in a small highly specialized area.

I love to understand new concepts and teach them to others, hence the reason I started out for Ph.D. (so that I can settle down as a Prof).  Now I am not sure if I am preparing myself for a career in academia as most of the time I just keep working on Code - There is nothing new to learn so that I can teach to my future students.

I expected research to be more theoretically enriching but it is turning out to be the exact opposite.

These long hours have already taken a toll on me. I am missing out on the 'enjoy your research part'. When I started out, I had this zeal for research and enjoyed the work. It has been one year.  Now, I just want to publish whatever results I have already with us, in any 2-tier journal/conference, without further go down this route.

But, my professor expects me to keep trying.

Sometimes, I feel I am better off with any supervisor. At least, I can study stuff which I like to.

Comment: Why do you assume a success rate of 5 / 10, some do hundreds of tests to find the one that works...

Comment: I guess the success rate varies from field to field. It is not number of experiments that matter. It is time and effort that takes in for each one. In my case, each avenue/detour/experiment takes around a month.

Comment: it is not the journey traveled, but the destination - find the correct answer is the pot of gold...

Comment: What do you want to do?  You mention stopping your current line of research, but then what?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: Oh, I forgot that. I want shift towards more theoretical Math-based CSE research. At least, the downside in theoretical research is that at the end of the day, if my results were not good, at least I have the satisfaction of learning something new. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how to fail and how to take away lessons from that failure. Have you brought your concerns to your professor? Research isn't all great success and code well most of the time it's determining why the code fairies won't compile your instructions.

Comment: "At least, 5 out of 10 attempts should be successful, I guess." That is stunningly unrealistic. Research involves discovering things that *no human has done before.* My lab and I recently brainstormed ~60 projects. I'd guess that many will end up dead ends; many will lead to new questions, even more interesting than the originals; a few will be straightforward & successful in the short term. But we're excited about *all* of the projects because, as noted in a good comment above, we are excited about the journey, not the destination. Research is very different than what you seem to think it is!

Comment: _my prof is not sure if a particular line of research of work may be successful or not_ — This is a *good* sign.  If he were sure that the line of work would be successful, it wouldn't be research!

Comment: This is a rant, not a question.

Comment: What is ironic about this situation?

Comment: @JeffE: Haha.. What I meant was an adviser should also get his hands dirty. It should not be that he/she asks his students to be mule boys and keep trying his ideas, without ever trying to derive the equations or writing the code, I mean ever. At least, there should a theoretical justification why a chosen avenue might lead to interesting results - That sort of uncertainity is completely fair. 

However, the advisor should not expect ppl to grope in the dark, if we accidentally stumble onto good results. That's like Telsa vs Edison.

Comment: @kasa Welcome to reality I guess... (Depending on the country.) You will frequently find that advisers will be more and more pre-occupied with obtaining research grants, admin and courting industry than with day to day supervision of their PhD students as they gain a more senior status. You will also find advisers who will hand out a rough topic and then let the PhD student decide what the work on exactly (a certain experience with certain people in the UK). - The younger the advisor, the more likely he/she is actively involved.

Comment: @JeffE Well, not necessarily. For some topics you know that an answer to a specific question can be obtained. The difficulty lies in obtaining the answer. I am thinking specifically of investigating specific chemical reactions or maybe creating chemical reaction mechanisms. All fairly active research areas. Generally the problem lies in the complexity of the whole, so that people will generally chip away at a specific aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in a bad spot and it is difficult to diagnose the disease, much less the cure. It may be that your advisor is inexperienced - some things you say indicate that. But as commenters have implied, some problems worth solving are just hard - damn hard. I once worked on such a problem and had to abandon it, but the professor agreed and we found a better one.

However, it may be that your "best" solution is to find a different advisor. That can be difficult (or impossible) as there is department politics to consider. Some large departments even have factions. The radical solution is to change universities and thus find a different professor with different ideas.

But a student working on an extremely hard problem is itself a problem since it takes time and the student would like to actually graduate before the Sun goes nova. I also worked on problems that were too easy (mathematics) and hence had no real merit. The trick is to find the sweet spot of a sufficiently hard but do-able problem. Not all professors have the ability to to that regularly.

But you need to judge. If the problem is hard, but its solution would be a significant advance *and* you have the time and resources to pursue it, it can result in a big win. But the win isn't guaranteed.

However. It also sounds like your current advisor is truly invested in you. Two meetings a week shows commitment. You won't always find that in an advisor.

You might try two things. First is to have a conversation about the likelihood of actual success in a reasonable time frame. The other part of the conversation is to try to set a limit on attempts and explore alternative problems that don't completely ignore what you have done so far. If your advisor is, in fact, invested in you and not just in the problem itself, that conversation might be possible.

As a first year doctoral student it isn't yet time to panic, in fact. Significant things take time and focus.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like a perfectly normal PhD student.

Your supervisor sounds okay.  At least he shows up for meetings!

Look out for your own interests, but don't worry so much.